# How to change the font style of text

Tags: c#, .net, fonts, styles

How can I change the Font Style (regular, bold, etc) ?

So far what I have is this:

```
if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == 3)
{
   if (textBox1.Text == "regular")
   {
     //FontStyle regular = new FontStyle   !!!wrong one!!!
   }
}
```

So what i need is that when I'd type "regular" in the textbox, the font style will change to regular. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new Font and apply it to your text box:

```
textBox1.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 12.0F, FontStyle.Normal);
```

This will create one with a new family etc. You can read the size and family from the existing Font object to preserve those.

```
textBox1.Font = new Font(textBox1.Font, FontStyle.Normal);
```

For more information on the properties of the Font class see [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Font_properties.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [Control.FontWeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.fontweight.aspx) property

```
if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == 3)
{
      if (textBox1.Text == "regular")
      {         
          TextBox1.FontWeight = FontWeights.Regular;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
textBox1.Font = new Font(textBox1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
```